# How to change/set multiple bar colors in matplotlib bar chart (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

Im having trouble changing the color for each of the bar in my bar chart
i want to change 'Administrative & Support Staff','Others' to different color help..
my current code is

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

ax1 = tt.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,10), fontsize=13)
#legend = plt.legend(loc=2, fontsize=8)
for tick in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(0)

ax1.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)
# ax1 = plt.gca()
# leg = ax1.get_legend()
# leg.legendHandles[1].set_color('yellow')

plt.show()
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izsSn.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

ax1 = tt.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,10), fontsize=13, color = ['#1b9e77', '#a9f971', '#fdaa48'])

for tick in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(0)

ax1.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)


plt.show()
```

got it